# Jupyter Lab Keyboard Shorcut To Focus FileBrowser

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut that will toggle the File Browser and switch focus to it so that I can use my keyboard to navigate the directory tree.

Toggle is already implemented, but I can't find a setting that will focus the file browser.

I have experimented with all of the `filebrowser:[COMMAND]` settings in the Keyboard Shortcuts file. I would have thought `filebrowser:activate` would be the relevant setting to use; however, it doesn't seem to produce any result at all.

What is the correct setting/command for focussing the file browser?

Thank you!

w

Comment: We are improving the file browser for JupyterLab 3.1 substantially. It looks like a fix to https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10401 might help here; I think I may have some time for coding this weekend - would you like to test it when ready and let me know if it solves this problem as well?

Comment: Yes, it seems like that proposed fix might solve my problem! I'd be happy to test it when it's ready. Thanks!

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work or have you managed to solve it? Please post the solution in that case